# The background lines of my Area Chart are not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, charts

I can't see the lines of the graph in the background, it's all black, attached the code of my graph:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Filler,
    Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Filler,
    Legend
);

interface ICodingTimeChart {
    width: string
}

export const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
    },
};

const CodingTimeChart = (props: ICodingTimeChart) => {

    const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState({
        labels: ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Minutes of Coding',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(144, 202, 249)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(72 , 101, 124)',
                fill: true
            }
        ]
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://wakatime.com/share/@FabioTambu/557e572d-e339-4765-9ea9-e0a7240b8ba8.json").then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.data[0]);
                setFetchData({
                    labels: [result.data[0].range.date, result.data[1].range.date, result.data[2].range.date, result.data[3].range.date, result.data[4].range.date, result.data[5].range.date, result.data[6].range.date],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Minutes of Coding',
                            data: [
                                Number((result.data[0].grand_total.total_seconds / 60).toFixed(0)),
                                Number((result.data[1].grand_total.total_seconds / 60).toFixed(0)),
                                Number((result.data[2].grand_total.total_seconds / 60).toFixed(0)),
                                Number((result.data[3].grand_total.total_seconds / 60).toFixed(0)),
                                Number((result.data[4].grand_total.total_seconds / 60).toFixed(0)),
                                Number((result.data[5].grand_total.total_seconds / 60).toFixed(0)),
                                Number((result.data[6].grand_total.total_seconds / 60).toFixed(0)),
                            ],
                            backgroundColor: 'rgb(72 , 101, 124)',
                            borderColor: 'rgb(144, 202, 249)',
                            fill: true
                        }
                    ]
                })
            });

    }, [])
    return (
        <Line options={options} data={fetchData} style={{width: props.width}}></Line>
    )
}

export { CodingTimeChart }
```

Could someone kindly tell me how I could try to solve this problem?
Maybe in the options you can decide whether or not to see the background lines or for example change their color.
Any help would be great.

This is the photo:

[image: Photo]